# Spotify web-api pause event listener

Tags: javascript, metadata, spotify, asp.net-web-api

We are creating an advertiser page for spotify.

When using the Spotify web-api to search and play a track, is it possible to listen to whether the user has paused the track in Spotify. It seems that Facebook have done this, but I'm not sure how, or if there is any documentation out there for this.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word, no, unless you're writing an application inside the Apps API.

The Web API doesn't support playback control at all — I assume you're actually launching a `spotify:` URI or an `open.spotify.com` HTTP URL. Unfortunately there are no corresponding URLs to actually control playback.